# Setting a char value to a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am making a `3x3` matrix using a 2d array. The array will initially display all `-`. Afterwhich I try to update the some values of the array to `1` and `2`. But the display still shows all `-` without updating the values of the array.

```java
private char[][] matrix;

public Matrix() {
    matrix = new char[3][3];
}

// setter and getter
public void set(int rowIndex, int colIndex, char data) {
    matrix[rowIndex][colIndex] = data;
}

public int get(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
    return matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];
}

// display the matrix
public void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = '-';
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void println(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.display();
    matrix.set(0, 0, '1');
    matrix.println("");
    matrix.display();
    matrix.set(0, 1, '2');
    matrix.println("");
    matrix.display();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `display()` method is always resetting the values of the array to `-` before printing it.
You should remove that line from the method.
If you want to initialize your matrix with certain values you should do that in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```java
private char[][] matrix;

public Matrix() {
    matrix = new char[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }
}

// setter and getter
public void set(int rowIndex, int colIndex, char data) {
    matrix[rowIndex][colIndex] = data;
}

public char get(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
    return matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];
}

// display the matrix
public void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void println(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.display();
    matrix.set(0, 0, '1');
    matrix.println("");
    matrix.display();
    matrix.set(0, 1, '2');
    matrix.println("");
    matrix.display();
}
```

try this!!